# How can I set tags on ec2 instances created by elastic-beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, tags, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Is there a way to do this from Beanstalk?
or do I have to do it myself once the new instance is up via .ebextensions or something like that?

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to set tags from .ebextensions? I'm trying to tag the attached volume and am surprised how little info is out there.

Comment: No. By now I HATE elastic beanstalk. You should *recreate* beanstalk envs whenever you have changes to apply and switch the CNAME. That's the best recommendation I can give you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature was not available at the time this question was asked. There were [many requests](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=151134) for this ever since the tagging feature was first [introduced in 2014](https://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/release-amazon-elastic-beanstalk-on-2014-04-22/).

Support for updating EB tags was eventually [added](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/10/aws-elastic-beanstalk-supports-ability-to-update-tags/) in [Oct 2017](https://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/release-elastic-beanstalk-support-for-updating-environment-tags-on-october-13-2017/).

You can now manage tags in the [Beanstalk Management Console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.tagging.html#using-features.tagging.manage), with the [EB CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-tags.html) or with the [AWS CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/elasticbeanstalk/update-tags-for-resource.html?shortFooter=true).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the tags from within your Elastic Beanstalk instance, you can certainly SSH in, install the AWS CLI and set the tags via the command line.  Or, whatever application you're deploying on Beanstalk can do so via the SDK (e.g. Java).

**Via CLI:**
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/create-tags.html

```
create-tags [--dry-run | --no-dry-run] --resources <value> --tags <value> [--cli-input-json <value>] [--generate-cli-skeleton]
```

**Via SDK:**
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/model/CreateTagsRequest.html

(pseudo-code)

```
Authorize via credentials
Instantiate CreateTagsRequest with specific resource ID
call setTags(Collection<<**String**>> tags) on the CreateTagsRequest object
```

---

From outside the environment, you can set the tags via the console or via EB CLI.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.tagging.html

```
eb create --tags mytag1=value1,mytag2=value2
```

Note, you can also set regular environment variables via eb create.

```
eb create --envvars key=value
```

Comment: I meant I'd like the tags to 'stick' also when instances are replaced. I think this article has got it right: http://www.boringgeek.com/add-or-update-tags-on-existing-elastic-beanstalk-environments/

Answer (score 0):

Answer
1. In order to have tags in elastic beanstalk that would be applied on any ec2 instance created for that environment - they must be set during the creation of the environment.
2. For existing environments, it's very simple to save configurations, create an alternative environment, set the tags right, and swap the URLs until you get your original env configured right.

This guy explains it well: http://www.boringgeek.com/add-or-update-tags-on-existing-elastic-beanstalk-environments/